# Why do I need to run php artisan optimize after adding a route

Tags: laravel, caching, routes, laravel-artisan

If I do not run `php artisan optimize` and I go to a new route in the browser I get **Page not found**

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you push a new version of your project to **production** it is recommended to run `php artisan route:cache`.

On **dev environment** it is recommended to have no cache and ensure that by running `php artisan route:clear`.

---

When you do

```
php artisan route:cache
```

A file like `bootstrap\cache\routes-v7.php` gets created holding all your routes from `routes\*.php` which are contained in `Route` methods that weight some calculation cost on your server each time you send a request to figure what to do for the current route.

Quoting from `bootstrap\cache\routes-v7.php` comments:

> This allows us to instantaneously load the entire route map into the router.

Important:

- This cache file doesn't get auto updates and doesn't exist in a fresh project.
- This cache takes precedence over `routes\*.php` files.
- The `bootstrap\cache` folder is ignored by default by **git**.

Here is an extensive great article for more details https://voltagead.com/laravel-route-caching-for-improved-performance/

Note that the `optimize` [command](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/OptimizeCommand.php#L37) was [removed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/20851) from the framework then [added](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/23468) back.